# Round time interval up to 15 minute steps

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario, where the user can push a button start a stopwatch and then push it again to stop it. But there's a twist - the end time needs to be rounded up in 15 minute steps. E.g. if the start time is `08:13` and the end time `08:16`, it needs to be rounded up to `08:28`. Or if the interval is longer than 15 minutes like `08:31`, it needs to be rounded up to `08:43`.

Do any of you have any pointers of how I could tackle this situation? If what I'm asking is too complicated, how do I round up and down to the closest 15 minutes (respectively).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking (`8:18` is just 5 minutes from `8:13`).

Comment: @hon2a Sorry, I made a mistake, I have fixed my answer

Comment: @Leo Sorry for the confusion, just realized that my edit was wrong. I have updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be pretty simple:

```
var interval = 15 * 60 * 1000,    // 15 minutes in miliseconds
    roundedTime = new Date(startTime + (Math.ceil((endTime - startTime) / interval) * interval));
```

where `startTime` and `endTime` are `Date` objects.